# Replace (and print) \qedsymbol within ntheorem proofs

Tags: latex, enumerate, proof

I'm trying to use ntheorem to complete proofs, but having some problems because it has been not possible to replace the \qedsymbol after an enumerate group and at the end of an align* group, the \qed symbol has been not printed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Conjunto de símbolos matemáticos
%\usepackage{amsthm}  % Formato para enunciados y demostraciones
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%

\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
%\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
%
\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
%
\begin{document}


\chapter*{Preface}
$\blacksquare$ \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
%
%
\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
    x+y &= z + k\\
    &= z + 2k
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

... Result has been
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You can change the qed symbol with `\gdef\proofSymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}`
- as for the `align` environment: you are missing the `amsmath` option for the `ntheorem` package

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Conjunto de símbolos matemáticos
%%\usepackage{amsthm}  % Formato para enunciados y demostraciones
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%%

\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}

\gdef\proofSymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}

\begin{document}


\chapter*{Preface}
$\blacksquare$ \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
%
%
\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
    x+y &= z + k\\
    &= z + 2k
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]